# Why does the generic type appear twice in method signatures?

Tags: c#, generics

why do we need to use type twice in following method

```
public void Search<T>(T bo) { }
```

Can we just declare

```
public void Search(T bo){}.
```

Can't find this answers? Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The first `T` is used by the compiler to determine what type the parameter should be.  The second `T` is used to tell the compiler that you want a parameter of that type.

Comment: I've edited your title to make your question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the snippet:

```
public void Search<T>(T bo);
```

The `<T>` specifies that there is a *type parameter* called `T`. Then, `T bo` specifies that there is a parameter of type `T`, which will be referred to as `bo` inside the method.

If you don't include the `<T>` part, the compiler has no way of knowing that `bo` is a generic argument and not just an instance of a class called `T`.

It may make it easier to understand if you know that the following achieves exactly the same thing:

```
public void Search<Something>(Something bo);
```

If the `<Something>` part was excluded, there'd be nothing to distinguish this from a normal method that takes an instance of a class called `Something`:

```
public void Search(Something bo);
```

To respond to your second question:

> Will it not make sense to just have `public void Search(<T> bo)`?

This wouldn't work as the generic type is not necessarily used a parameter. Nor is it necessarily the return type. It may not appear elsewhere in the method signature at all. A trivial example might be:

```
public bool IsType<T>(object input)
{
    return input.GetType() == typeof(T);
}
```

In this case, the type parameter is absolutely necessary. There may be some scenarios where it could be inferred using syntax like you suggest, but this would lead to all kinds of inconsistencies in different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Ant and everyone, this was so much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

How could compiler possibly know that `T` is a generic argument or a type ? Can't you have a class or a struct named `T` ? then, how should the compiler handle this situation ?

Consider this:

```
class Foo { }

static void DoSomething(Foo f) { }
```

In this case should `DoSomething`  be a *generic* or *non-generic* ? there is no way to decide that according to your logic.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
public void Search(T bo){}.
```

It says `T` is a input parameter, but doesn't says what is `T`, It is perfectly fine to have a class name `T` that will be ambigious. So by the following we say the compiler that `T` is a generic parameter.

```
public void Search<T>(T bo) { }
```

Also note that when you're inside a generic class you can do as version1. For example

```
class Test<T>
{
     public void Search(T bo){}.
}
```

This is completely legal. because we know T is a generic parameter which you should provide while constructing the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's needed to avoid ambiguity, because `T` is a valid a type by itself. Suppose you wrote:

```
Search(T bo){}
```

And elsewhere you had:

```
public class T { }
```

The compiler must interpret `T` as a reference to the class `T`, not to a generic type argument.

The `<T>` after the method (or class) name identifies that `T` **not** a normal class name, but a generic type argument within the *context* of this method (or class).

Comment: For all the answers above, will it not make sense to just have                         public void Search(<T> bo).

Comment: @MeProgramming That might be a valid alternative syntax, but that's just not how the C# team designed the language. Note that [F# has something somewhat like that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233215.aspx) (e.g. `search (bo : 'A) = ...`)